# c array with property in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am using the next code to define my c array (which works great except warning) :

**on .h file :**

```
@interface memory : NSObject 
{
     int places[60];
     int lastRecordSound;  
}

@property int *places;
```

then in my `.m` i am not synchronize it(and it works) but if i try to synchronize it like:

```
@synthesize places;
```

i get error :

```
type of preperty "places does not match type of ivar places (int[60] )
```

and if not, i get warnning :

```
auto synthesized property places will be use synthesized instance variable _places...
```

**So, what is the best way to define this c array ?** ( yes I need c .. )

Comment: `@synchronized` and `@synthesize` are two different keywords.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> @synchronize places;

you have to write

> @synthesize places;

Also change iVar from `int places[60];` to `int *places;` or even you can completely remove these lines.

Comment: also , remove this line or change it to places, will give me so many errors so its not the way.

Comment: I have tried declaring in the same manner and its working in mine code, could you please copy your code here where you are accessing place array.

Answer (score 0):

This? (non-ARC)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Memory:NSObject
@property int *places;
@end

@implementation Memory
@synthesize places;
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int *p;
    if( p = malloc(60 * sizeof(int)) ) {
        p[1] = 99;
        Memory *aMemory = [[Memory alloc] init];
        aMemory.places = p;

        int *q = aMemory.places;
        printf("q[1] = %d\n",q[1]);

        free(p);
        [aMemory release];
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR: unable to malloc p\n");
    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Prints `q[1] = 99` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The automatically generated accessor functions cannot associate a `int *` property with an `int[]` array. But it works if you declare the property as

```
@property(readonly) int *places;
```

in your .h file, and provide a custom getter function

```
- (int *)places
{
    return self->places;
}
```

in your .m file.

Now you can access the array through the property:

```
memory *mem = [[memory alloc] init];
mem.places[23] = 12;
```

Of course, the compiler does not know that the array has only 60 elements, so you will not get a compiler warning if you assign

```
mem.places[999] = 12;
```

and everything bad can happen.

Declaring the property as `read-only` makes sense because you cannot change the address of the int array. (You may also want to add `nonatomic` to the property attributes if you don't need synchronized access, but that is a different topic.)